# Fire Domain color ramp affects whole scene

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

If I have a simple node setup like the following:
[image]
Then when I render it looks like this:
[image]
Whereas if I disconnect the bottom node path (with the color ramp), it looks normal again, but the flames don't render.
[image]

Comment: Add another Control point to Color Ramp (+ button) with pure black color and slide it full left before orange.

Comment: how big is the volume this is applied to?

Comment: Nice, I'm going to use those effects for watercolour background. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your material lights up the entire Smoke / Fire domain instead of just the flame part.

Put the *Fac* output of the *Attribute* "flame"-node into the *Strength* input of the *Emission* node. You might need to insert a *Math* node between those and multiply the value to get a brighter flame.